# How to download to a USB Drive instead of systems hard drive? Ubuntu 20.04 To be Exact

Tags: usb, directory, disk-usage, drive

Can somebody show me step by step commands?

this is what I get when I do the command "lsblk", I am trying to use the ROCKY one, which is a clear USB Drive/Flash Drive:

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1    7:1    0  63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1828
loop2    7:2    0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop3    7:3    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop4    7:4    0    46M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/638
loop5    7:5    0  49.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18357
sda      8:0    0  58.3G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  47.2G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0   466M  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  10.4G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1 115.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1  63.5G  0 part /media/khalilw1226/ROCKY-9-3-X
├─sdb2   8:18   1   513M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   1     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   1  51.5G  0 part /media/khalilw1226/046D-D70E
sdc      8:32   1  14.5G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1  14.5G  0 part /media/khalilw1226/UBUNTU 20_0
```

Also I am using a Terminal on Ubuntu 20.04 Full Desktop Version and dont have enough space to download using a command in the Terminal, I only have 1.4GB space left and trying to download using my USB Drive instead.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Please add exactly what command you want to use in the terminal. Depending on the command, there may be a way to specify download location.

Comment: `df -Th` shows you a nice overview of what filesystems are mounted and their used/available space, or plain old `mount` will say if they're writeable (`ro`) but there's a lot of things that aren't physical partitions shown too. It looks like your ROCKY partition is mounted at /media/khalilw1226/ROCKY-9-3-X so just point your downloads to save there... or does that not work? Also seeing 47.2G sda3 that's not mounted, but it could be another OS. PS baobab could show what's using your disk space

Comment: What happens when you try the following command: `echo hello > /media/khalilw1226/ROCKY-9-3-X/hello.txt` ? If success, you can write to that partition. Otherwise, please edit your original question and show the following command and the output from it: `grep ROCKY /etc/mtab`

Comment: What program are you trying to use in order to download your data? Is it a single file or a set of files (that you want to download)? What total size?

Comment: cd to directory you want to save into. Quicker if you already have the file & want to update it as then it only downloads changes. Then zsync, `man zsync` You can use this: `zsync http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jammy/daily-live/current/jammy-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync` if that if the file you want. If first time it just downloads the entire file. I often copy & rename an older version, so only updates are downloaded.